# badblocks: Resource busy while trying to determine device size

Tags: terminal, badblocks

I am trying to run bad blocks on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6. I installed bad blocks using macports. I keep encountering errors when attempting to run it and I am not sure how to even get bad blocks running

```
sudo badblocks -c 4096 -s -w -o /Users/mcbeav/Desktop/blocks.txt /dev/disk0s2
```

This keeps returning the error

**badblocks: Resource busy while trying to determine device size**

If I try

```
sudo badblocks -c 4096 -s -w -o /Users/mcbeav/Desktop/blocks.txt /dev/disk0
```

I get the error

**badblocks: Value too large to be stored in data type invalid end block (7813820416): must be 32-bit value**

Comment: Are you sure about using the `-w` parameter? The `badblocks` man page advises not to use it on an existing file system.

Comment: Does your filesystem contain an NFS Mount?

Answer (score 0):

You should try using dumpe2fs. Or use a Linux live CD/USB, with persistence and use badblocks on the unmounted drive. As using badblocks on a mounted drive is not going to work properly.

```
dumpe2fs -b /dev/sda
```

Note remember to use the path to your drive, as it may differ from my example.